# What are the Bhakti ways of worshipping the mahavidyas?

Tags: dasha-mahavidya, bhakti-mantras, bhakti-worship

I am interested to achieve higher things in both the material and spiritual world. I have been trying to find about the mahavidyas and other deities . From this I came to know that to achieve higher things I can worship the mahavidyas but most of them I have heard needs some clarification. The worship of mahavidyas are usually tantric to get results very fast and if not done with proper ritual , initiation of guru and any mistakes then the effects can be drastic, which I do-not want. But , I have heard that there are Bhakti ways of worship where I will get results gradually and no harms will be caused( examples include the chanting of Rama nama and putting water or milk on the shiva linga). As I visually see , Chinnamasta is a very *ugra devi*. So any mistake in the tantrik practice will either cause siddhi or death. Hence I want to avoid the tantrik practice. But , is there any Bhakti ways of worshipping Chinnamasta and other mahavidyas to get siddhis without getting any harm?

By Bhakti ways I mean , chanting the name of the mahavidya like *Om chinnamastaya namaha*,*om dhumavatiye namaha*,*om tara namaha* etc, in front of their images? Or are there any other ways to worship them in Bhakti ways?